# Universal 100% div height

Tags: html, height, doctype

I'm trying to get a div to be 100% height. This is what I had, that wasn't working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<head>
</head> 

<body>
    <div style="height: 100%; border: solid 1px red">
        Not working
    </div>  
</body>

</HTML>
```

...but removing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` makes it work:

```
<HTML>

<head>
</head> 

<body>
    <div style="height: 100%; border: solid 1px red">
        Not working
    </div>  
</body>

</HTML>
```

It seems the version of HTML I set the page to use affects whether it works.

I'm under the impression that using something like `<!DOCTYPE html>` is a good thing to have at the start, so my questions are these:

1) What's the best thing to have on the first line?

2) Given that, how do I then get 100% height in div blocks?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it in many browsers? You'll find removing the doctype will cause more issues that it solves.

Comment: A basic principle: to have width/height set to a 100%, this 100% is based on the element's parent - so, where's the body height definition?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should have the doctype there! To allow divs to go to 100% height, their parents' height needs to be set. In this case:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

### Question: 1) What's the best thing to have on the first line?

**Answer:  USE The DOCTYPE.**

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is the explicit [Document Type Declaration](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/doctype-declaration.htm).

From the linked page:

> The DOCTYPE Declaration (DTD or Document Type Declaration) does a couple of things:
>
> 1. When performing HTML validation testing on a web page it tells the HTML (HyperText Markup Language) validator which version of (X)HTML standard the web page coding is supposed to comply with. When you validate your web page the HTML validator checks the coding against the applicable standard then reports which portions of the coding do not pass HTML validation (are not compliant).
> 2. It tells the browser how to render the page in standards compliant mode.

Bullet point #2 is a very important reason for using it.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`, specifically, is the [correct declaration for HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype), and should be used pretty much from here to the near future.  You can still use legacy strings or obsolete permitted strings, but the previously written format is all that is required in HTML5. On a further note, this DTD will cause [all modern browsers](http://themaingate.net/dev/html/all-you-need-is-doctype-html) to [switch to their standards (compliance) mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/), even if they don't support HTML5.

Here's some more info:

[Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)
[World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) (they make web standards)

---

### Question: 2) Given that, how do I then get 100% height in div blocks?

**Answer: You MUST set the html and body to be 100%.**

The `DIV` is 100% of its parent height (your `BODY`), it's just that your `BODY` and `HTML` elements are not 100% of your BROWSER height.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways of doing this.

Making the div position absolute:

```
<body style="margin:0px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; border: solid 1px red; position:absolute;box-sizing:border-box;">
        Not working
    </div>  
</body>
```

Setting the `html` and `body` to a height of 100% (its parent)

```
<html style="height:100%;">  
    <body style="height:100%;margin:0px;">
        <div style="height: 100%; border: solid 1px red; box-sizing:border-box;">Not working</div>
    </body>
</html>
```